# wingetでインストールしようとしたらエラーが出ます。

Tags: windows

wingetでインストールしようとしたら

winget: The term 'winget' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

このように出ます。よろしくお願いします。

[image: スクリーンショット]

Comment: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/winget-not-recognized-in-windows-11
このサイトの環境変数を入れたら動作しました。違う環境変数を入れていました。

Answer (score 0):

おそらくスタートメニューの「設定」→「アプリ」→「アプリ実行エイリアス」の設定画面で、python.exe,python3.exeと共に`winget.exe`(Windows Package Manager Client)も`オフ`にしてしまったのだと思われます。
その設定を`オン`に変更してからPowerShellを立ち上げてみてください。

こちらはpython関連の設定に関する質問記事ですが、質問のスクリーンショットにwinget.exeも表示されています。
[アプリ実行エイリアスの「pytnon.exe」と「python3.exe」とは何ですか？](https://teratail.com/questions/m3gp2f5lxrwo49)

---

コメントで解決した件について：

以下のように一応デフォルトで組み込み済みのはずですが、

[winget ツールを使用したアプリケーションのインストールと管理](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/package-manager/winget/)

> Windows パッケージ マネージャーの **winget** コマンドライン ツールは、既定では、**アプリ インストーラー** として Windows 11 と最新バージョンの Windows 10 にバンドルされています。

以下のような感じで何か追加作業を行って設定が変わったのかもしれませんね。
[winget プレビュー バージョンをインストールする [開発者のみ]](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/package-manager/winget/#install-winget-preview-version-developers-only)

Comment: 私が知る限り、新規にインストールした直後のWindows11であっても必ずしも[AppInstaller](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA-%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC/9NBLGGH4NNS1?hl=ja-jp&gl=jp)はインストールされているわけではなく、その後自動的に（スケジューラ？）インストールされるような挙動だった気がします。

Comment: なるほど、何かの機能の有効化やオプション設定等で入るのかもしれませんね。